Obtain a list of RPM packages to update a system
I would appreciate your help with the following. I have a system (Centos 9 with additional repos) and I have a snapshot for its repo, it was installed from. Let's say it is BASE repo.
Now I update it from several sources with dnf, so new versioned rpms appear and some are updated or removed.
How can I get a list of RPMs that were used to update my system together with URLs so I could manage to update similar systems that were installed from BASE without network / downloading these update packages every time?
So basically I need a RPM diff between pre-updated system and updated one, so I could download update RPMs and install them.
Thank you

What about sync your repo with CentOS repo with one command?

There is no Internet access for most of workstations, LAN only, so I need to place all *.rpm that participate in update on a flashdrive. As there are a lot of different systems, I want this place occupied by update rpm's to be as small as possible. Preferably it sould be a delta betweeen original system state and repository/set of them.

The base + apps repos (RHEL, I do not have CentOS) is ~ 20GB. So flash drive can be used. To use packages can be cumbersome because of packages dependencies.

Exactly, the question is mostly about that: to get a list of packages with their dependencies. Yes, if there is no simple way, I would go with a full repo on a flash.

Based on this answer you can get the history of dnf executions with the commands
dnf history

then you select which of the history ID you want to see in details with command:
dnf history info <ID>

and under Packages Altered you will see the package and the repo from where it is installed.
The you can download desired packages with command:
dnf download --resolve <package name>

If you decide to make a mirror of desired repo you can use command like:
dnf reposync --repoid=<ID of the repo> --destdir=<destination directory>

The destination directory must exist!
